# TypeError: json is undefined in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I am trying to use `Jquery dataTable` in `MVC 4`. Below is my Code.

**Web Method :**

```
   public JsonResult GetProjects()
   {
          //   ...............
          //   ...............

        return Json(new
                  {
                     sEcho = param.sEcho,
                     iTotalRecords = result.Count(),
                     iTotalDisplayRecords = result.Count(),
                     aaData = result
                   }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```

**View**

```
<table id="JProject" class="table table-advance dataTable">
   <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Sno</th>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>NameArabic</th>
         <th>Town</th>
         <th>StartDate</th>
         <th>EndDate</th>
         <th>StringType</th>
         <th>StringStatus</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScritpt:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var oTable = $("#JProject").dataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Project/GetProjects",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": function (data) {
                        fnCallback(data.d);
                    }
                });
            },
            "aoColumns": [
            {
                "mDataProp": "NameArabic",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true,
                "sWidth": "20px"
            },
            {
                "mDataProp": "Name",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": true
            },
             {
                 "mDataProp": "NameArabic",
                 "bSearchable": true,
                 "bSortable": true
             },
            {
                "mDataProp": "StartDate",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false

            },
            {
                "mDataProp": "EndDate",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false

            },

            {
                "mDataProp": "StringType",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false
            },
            {
                "mDataProp": "StringStatus",
                "bSearchable": true,
                "bSortable": false
            },
            {
                "mData": null,
                "sWidth": "20px",
                "bSearchable": false,
                "bSortable": false

            }
            ]
        });

    });
```

Web Method is called successfully, and i can also see my required `Data` in `FireBug`, but it is not shown in dataTable. In `FireBug` i got the error

**TypeError: json is undefined**

**if ( json.sEcho !== undefined )**

Comment: post `fnCallback` also..

Comment: What is `data.d`? The values your returning in the `GetProjects()` method do not contain a property named `d`

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke, that was the problem..